# Как сделать фон блока div html не до конца

Tags: html, css

есть счет, допустим на 100 рублей, но оплата по счету бывает не полная и в ячейку заносится 30 рублей.

как сделать блок, чтобы фон его соответствовал проценту оплаты счета.
тоесть в блоке, в ячейке таблицы лежит число 30 рублей, это 30% от 100рублей, как сделать чтобы блок закрасился фоном слева на право на 30%

1. мне предлагали, делать разные картинки, мол на 5 на 10, 15 и тд процентов, и вставлять их в background в зависимости от суммы
2. мне предлагали использовать еще 1 див, но как я буду выводить сумму, если у дива будет изменяться ширина, сумма туда не влезет. (хотя щас подумал на счет суммы как абсолютно спозиционированной, а див будет внутри... попробую)

Если у кого есть более грамотное решение - пишите!

Comment: еще вариант создать php картинку
тоесть в style дива вставлять фоновую картинку с параметром ширины
fon.php?width=33

Comment: Сделал php картинкой. вообщем то что надо, круто! спасибо за советы.

Comment: Тут не всегда быстро реагируют, особенно в 2 часа ночи. Даже на StackOverflow вопросы, бывает, по пол-дня стоят без ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда я хотел сделать прогрессбар, мне [посоветовали](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1082148/116546) вот такое решение: http://jsfiddle.net/ehb3x/:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="wrapper" style="width: 53%;">
      <div class="white-on-black" style="width: 188.7%;">
           <span>This is a test</span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="black-on-white">
      <span>This is a test</span>
  </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid;
    text-align: center;
    width: 400px;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
}
.black-on-white {
    height: 32px;
    color: #000;
}
.white-on-black {
    height: 32px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #44a;
}
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}
.black-on-white { width: 100%; }
```

Вариант с динамически генерируемой картинкой не всегда хорош тем, что зависит от ширины контейнера в пикселях.

Comment: Такой градусник гораздо семантичнее, чем изображение. http://jsfiddle.net/vYLXF/

Comment: ну в этом варианте я так понял нужно высчитывать процент прогресса и исходя из него удлиннять в процентах надпись, чтоб она либо растягивалась либо сжималась?

  <div class="wrapper" style="width: 53%;">
      <div class="white-on-black" style="width: 188.7%;">

вот это если будет другой процент (53) нужно будет пересчитать значение (188.7)
кстати, классный сервис http://jsfiddle.net/ehb3x/

Comment: Еще есть `<progress>`, он идеален семантически, но сырой. Я пол-года назад пытался его стилизировать кроссбраузерно, но ничего не вышло.

Answer (score 1):

Если ширина контейнера известна, то делаете фоновую картинку точно под его размер, 
и помещаете её со смещением. Допустим, ширина контейнера 100px:

```
<div style="background:url(fon.png) y-repeat -70px 0">30%</div>
```

Логично делать такой бар фиксированной ширины, особенно, если их несколько на странице рядом друг с другом.

Если же ширина не фиксирована, нужно задействовать JS, который будет налету определять ширину контейнера и смещать фон на (100 - value)% влево.

Answer (score 1):

## Для современных браузеров:

```html
<progress min=0 max=100 value=30 />
```

## Стандартное решение:

```css
.progress {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 1em;
  width: 10em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.progress > div {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class=progress><div style=width:30%></div></div>
```

## Вариант с градиентом:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1em;
  width: 10em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, blue 0%, blue 30%, white 30%, white 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, blue), color-stop(30%, white), color-stop(30%, white), color-stop(100%, white));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, blue 0%, blue 30%, white 30%, white 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, blue 0%, blue 30%, white 30%, white 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, blue 0%, blue 30%, white 30%, white 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue 0%, blue 30%, white 30%, white 100%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Теоретически, можно в градиент упихать значение из атрибута, но практически, браузеры не поддерживают вытаскивание из атрибутов чего-то кроме текста.